# Adding more strings in wordpress smilies translation function... is it search engine friendly?

Tags: image, wordpress, seo, translation, search-engine

I actually want to replace some words with images .... inside the function.php i found the codes like this

```
':mrgreen:' => 'icon_mrgreen.gif',
':neutral:' => 'icon_neutral.gif',
':twisted:' => 'icon_twisted.gif',
':arrow:' => 'icon_arrow.gif',
':shock:' => 'icon_eek.gif',
':smile:' => 'icon_smile.gif',
':???:' => 'icon_confused.gif',
':cool:' => 'icon_cool.gif',
```

i added some strings with this code and it worked...

```
'wiring' => 'wiring.gif',
```

now the question is... if i continue translating words like this .... is it search engine friendly?? 
will search engine index these words properly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are using a function to replace words with images in your blog posts. If yes, then the above query will not work until unless you add some code with them as well. like:

```
':mrgreen:' => '<img src="icon_mrgreen.gif" alt="Smile" />',

':shock:' => '<img src= icon_eek.gif alt="Shocked" />',
```

(please don't mind minus sign before img tag :)

In that case, SEO will effect!

Comment: I actually replaced the text using the default wordpress smiley function.... when i checked the post with firebug .... image alt was automatically working... now if the alt is working.... will it effect the search engine .... or using just text is good option?

Comment: If alt tag is working properly then search engine will index the image unless it is set to be "noindex".